# GIT - Different http configs for different origins

Tags: git

I have a git directory which is downstream of two different origins. They both must connect via https, and both require different `[http]` config parameters.

The way git works (to my understanding) - is there is one config section for all of the HTTP parameters, and other configuration sections for *each* origin.

What I really want is to be able to specify *different* http parameters (such as `sslCert` and `sslKey`) for each origin.

Is there any way I can have such parameters be automatically applied for each origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you're looking for this:

> http.<url>.*
>
> Any of the http.* options above can be applied selectively to some URLs.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httplturlgt

Comment: Thanks - that definitely appears to be it - though my config settings like that don't seem to be getting applied when I do that. Don't know why - will have to investigate...

Comment: My git (on this system) -is older than 1.8.5 when this was added  - I will have to update - thanks ;-)